# Getting Text and Images from external web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I read many articles about how i can get our LinkedIn Recent Updates inside our external web site (which is an internal intranet for our company). now  those recent updates can be viewed by any user. for example if someone access our LinkedIn's account (where the url is something similar to https://www.linkedin.com/company/OurCompany***), then they can view the Recent Updates, without the need to login to LinkedIn.
But seems LinkedIn does not provide any API which can allow us to get these Recent Updates, unless the user is already login to LinkedIn (which will not work in our case). Also I was searching for something similar to RSS feeds, but seems LinkedIn does not provide any RSS feeds..

So i am thinking if i can get these Recent Updates by following these steps:-

1. using JavaScript to get the source code for our LinkedIn account web page @ https://www.linkedin.com/company/OurCompany***
2. then get the Recent Updates' Text & Images markup.
3. show the Text and Images markup inside our web site.

so i am not sure if following the above 3 steps should work for me?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work, because javascript inside of browsers is not allowed to use XHR to do HTTP requests to other domains unless they have an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set, which LinkedIn will not since scraping their webpages is against their terms of service.

See: [Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: thanks for the reply,, so is there any appraoch i can follow, that can allow me to get the markup for Images and Text from external web page? other than using APIs or RSS feeds?

Comment: @testtest You can have one of your own servers request these items and ignore cross-origin headers, and then have the javascript in browser query your own servers for those images and text.

Comment: so you mean i can not only rely on JavaScript? and i will need to write some server side code?